# How do I understand this sentence in Hartshorne Chapter 2?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

It is in Hartshorne Chapter 2 theorem 4.3.(at the top of page 99)

The theorem (Valuative Criterion of Separatedness) claims that a morphism $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is separated if and only if the following holds. For any field $K$ and any valuation ring $R$ with quotient field $K$, let $T=\operatorname{Spec}R$ and $U=\operatorname{Spec}K$, let $i: U\rightarrow T$ be the morphism induced by inclusion $R\subset K$, given morphisms $g_1: U\rightarrow X$ and $g_2: T\rightarrow Y$ such that $f\circ g_1=g_2\circ i$ (i.e. the diagram commutes). Then there is at most one morphism from $T$ to $X$ making the diagram still commuted.

In the proof of the theorem, Hartshorne first notes that if $h$ and $h'$ are two different morphism from $T$ to $X$, then by universal property of fibre product, we have an induced morphism $h'':T\rightarrow X\otimes X$, then he claimed that ***'since the restrictions of $h$ and $h'$ to $U$ are the same, the generic point $t_1$ of $T$ has image in the diagonal $\Delta (X)$.'*** Where this diagonal map，$\Delta: X\rightarrow X\otimes X$, is induced by two identities maps from $X$ to $X$.

I am confused that why the image is in the diagonal $\Delta (X)$? I think Hartshorne is saying $h(t_1)=h'(t_1)$, where $t_1$ is the generic point of $T$, because they restricted to the same map from $U$ to $X$, however I am not sure does this mean $h''(t_1)=\Delta(h(t_1))$?

Comment: What is $h''$ here?

Comment: Since there are two morphisms $h$ and $h'$ from $T$ to $X$, there is an induced morphism $h''$ from $T$ to $X \otimes X$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Not everyone has access to a copy of Hartshorne at the time they're reading your question. You'll have a better chance of getting help with your question if you put all the relevant parts of the text you're asking about in to your question - for instance, what are $U$, $h,h'$, $X$, $T$, etc.

Comment: Hi KReiser, sorry about that, I had updated the question, I am not entirely sure if this  is trivial but I must have missed something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $g:U\rightarrow X\times X$ to be the morphism induced by $g_1:U\rightarrow X$ (i.e. $g=g_1\times g_1$). Let $\pi_1 : X\times X \rightarrow X$ and $\pi_2 : X\times X \rightarrow X$ be the projection to each of the $X$ respectively. Then by definition, $\pi_1 \circ g =g_1$.

Now notice $\pi_1 \circ \Delta \circ h \circ i =id \circ g_1 = g_1$, then by universal property of $g$ (i.e. $g$ is the UNIQUE map such that $\pi_1 \circ g =g_1$), we have $\Delta \circ h \circ i = g$.

Similarly, notice $\pi_1 \circ h'' \circ i = h \circ i = g_1$, therefore $h'' \circ i = g$.

This means $h ''\circ i = \Delta \circ h \circ i$, which is the same as saying $h''(t_1)=\Delta(h(t_1))$.

Comment: One small note - when you invoke the universal property of the product, it is not enough to only use $\pi_1$, you also need that $\pi_2\circ \Delta\circ h \circ i= g_1$ to conclude that $\Delta\circ h\circ i = g.$

Answer (score 2):

The restrictions of $h$ and $h'$ to $U$ are the same, let's call them $a: U\to X$. Then the induced map $U\to X\times X$ given by restricting $h''$ is the same as the map to the product induced by the restrictions of $h$ and $h'$; i.e., it is the product of $a$ with itself. But $a\times a: U\to X\times X$ factors as $$U\xrightarrow{a}X\xrightarrow{\Delta}X\times X,$$ so the image of $U$ lies in the diagonal. Explicitly, this does mean that $h''(t_1)=\Delta(h(t_1))=\Delta(h'(t_1))$.

Comment: May I ask are we doing the same thing? Because I was not completely clear about your steps here :)

Comment: @Rikka it looks like we are, but you've included more detail than I have showing that the maps I claimed agree actually do.